# Can PhysFS use ifstreams?

Tags: c++, physfs

I have a problem. I have lots of code that uses ifstreams in this manner:

ex:

```
bool AudioManager::_loadSounds( const std::string& path, const std::string& appendPath )
{
    //open the file
    std::ifstream ifs( path.c_str() );

    //ensure it is open
    if(!ifs.is_open())
    {
        return false;
    }

    std::string line;

    //read each sound
    while( getline( ifs, line ) )
    {
```

...

The problem is I need to make an application-wide change to use PhysFS. All data will stay structured the same directory wise except it will be compartmentalized into zip files.

Is there a simple way to make PhysFS apply to ifstreams so that I do not need to modify all these classes?

Comment: Two suggestions, not related to question: 1) `fstream`s do have constructor taking `std::string` - why do you pass a `.c_str()` to it? 2) `fstream`s do have `operator bool()` defined; instead of `if (!ifs.is_open())`, use just `if (ifs)`.

Comment: @Griwes: The constructor that takes `std::string` is only in C++11.

Comment: @JesseGood, uh, forgot to mention that. Anyway, is there any reason not to compile with `-std=c++11`/`0x` nowadays?

Comment: @Griwes The code was written before c++11 was a standard.

Comment: I also find is_open clearer than !ifs because in my mind !ifs implies ifs is a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a *simple* way to do it. No matter what, you're going to have to not use fstreams. However, you can continue to use streams by simply writing a `std::streambuf`-derived class that pulls its data from PhysFS. This isn't a trivial thing, since `streambuf` has various bits of complexity to it. But it is certainly doable.

You can take any `istream`-derived class and shove a different `streambuf` into it.

Answer (score 0):

PhysFS is a C library, and has no concept of C++ types.  You will either need to find a C++ wrapper or write your own if you want to treat PhysFS handles as stream objects.